# Pass a closure in a function

Tags: swift

I have a little experience in Swift and facing a problem to pass a closure in a function as a parameter.

```
//1.
public func changeMyStatus(to f:?, _ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){
    //

}
//2.
func goLive(_ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){

}
//3.
func goNonLive(_ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){

}
```

Now , I want to use first function in my controller and wants to pass second/third function as a parameter. Closure in first will return true/false depending on what returned by closure in second/third.

i)What will be the type I should put in first function?

Also I want to call first function from my class like this

```
  changeMyStatus(to: goNonLive) { (isSuccess) in

    }
```

please help

Comment: The isSuccess that you want to call is it from your changeMyStatus function or your passed function goNonLive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `changeMyStatus` function signature and implementation like:

```
public func changeMyStatus(to f: (@escaping (Bool) -> ()) -> () , _ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){
    f { (status) in
        completion(status)
    }
}
```

You can call these function like:

```
// goLive
changeMyStatus(to: goLive(_:)) { (status) in
    print(status)
}


// goNonLive
changeMyStatus(to: goNonLive(_:)) { (status) in
    print(status)
}
```

Comment: One more question what will be the type of f if I change the function goLive and goNonLive to lke this

    
func goLive( _ myStr:String,_ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){

}

Comment: @Gour: It should be like : `f: (_ str : String, @escaping (Bool) -> ()) -> ()`

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third function has a completion parameter with a type of : `(Bool -> Void) -> Void`

So in order to pass it to your first function, try this way :

```
public func changeMyStatus(to f: ((Bool) -> ()), _ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()) { // Your body}
```

In Swift, you need to see a function as a type like Int, Double, String...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Arrabidas. But, you missed '@escaping' in f.

Comment: One more question what will be the type of f if I change the function goLive and goNonLive to lke this func goLive( _ myStr:String,_ completion:@escaping (_ isSucced:Bool)->()){ }

Comment: (String, @escaping (Bool) -> ()) -> ()